# Based Array(contains date) highlight date picker dates

Tags: android, datepicker

Based on array of date objects, I need to highlight or bold the dates which are contains in array in date picker in android.

Comment: Are you using spinner mode or calendar mode?

Answer (score 0):

There is no officially supported way of customizing DatePicker as you described. You can check out the source code for [android.widget.SimpleMonthView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/SimpleMonthView.java)#drawDays to see where the days of the month are rendered.